# Cisco MIB Locator

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, snmp

Cisco has a [MIB Locator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/MainServlet) which gives you a list of supported MIBs for a specific Cisco IOS Release. I have a MIB and need information on wich IOS version this MIB is supported. Does Cisco provide a database for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is on the same page you already have provided. On the bottom of the page there is a large box with the title `Search for MIB`. You can select your MIB in question there and click submit, which will lead you to another page where only the IOS/IOS-XE versions are listed which support your MIB. On this page you can narrow down the search by multiple factors, including:

- Release
- Platform Familiy
- Feature Set

The page will then provide you with IOS versions with this specific attributes that support your MIB.